# Redirect welcome page to a page in another domain in servlet container?

Tags: java, servlets

I tried

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>http://otherdomain.com/index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

but it does not work, also, i would like to redirect 404 error to a page in another domain too. Is it possible?

Comment: Its obvious that you will get page not found because http://otherdomain.com/index.html</welcome-file> will not be present in your project folder.Only those pages present in your project folder will work

Comment: From setting welcome-file you can not do this. You have to write a servlet and then in servlet you can write response.sendRedirect(url);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that's a strange requirement...

however:

index.jsp

```
<%@page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true" %>
<% response.sendRedirect("http://www.stackoverflow.com"); %>
```

web.xml:

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you can adress another domain directly. The tag is called "welcome-file", so URLs may not be possible. A workaround would be to create a welcome page and error page in the domain of the request and just redirect using HTML:

```
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=http://otherdomain.com/index.html"/>
</head>
```

Content is the number of seconds to wait till the user is redirected.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't redirect welcome page to a page in another domain in different servlet container.

**welcome-file-list**
The optional **welcome-file-list** element contains an ordered list of welcome-file elements.
When the URL request is a directory name, WebLogic Server serves the first file specified in this element. If that file is not found, the server then tries the next file in the list.